# How to map using hooks

Tags: reactjs, prismic.io

I want to show a list of elements from Prismic endpoint in React doing a map. But I'm blocked because I don't know how to do it with hooks.

This is my code so far and, as you can imagine, do not work:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { state, useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import Prismic from '@prismicio/client';
import { Date, Link, RichText } from 'prismic-reactjs'

const apiEndpoint = 'https://mydeponame.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2'
const accessToken = '' // This is where you would add your access token for a Private repository

const Client = Prismic.client(apiEndpoint)

 const App = ()=> {
    const [doc, setDocData] = React.useState(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await Client.query(
                Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'page')
            )
            if (response) {
                console.log(response.results[0].uid);
                setDocData(response.results[0])
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>testing2</p>
            {doc.map((user) => (
                <div key={user.uid}>
                    <p>{user.uid}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};


export default App;
```

And the error I'm getting is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: Are you getting any error or what ? I can see you are making api call and also saving response in state. 
But initially as `doc` is assigned `null` so it wont invoke .map method on it. and will crash app.
So may be you can replace `doc.map` by `doc?.map`.

Comment: What do you get as result during the maping doc ??

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to add the error result which is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null"

Comment: You explicitly set doc as null to start with, why is that surprising?

Comment: changing React.useState(null) to React.useState([])

I am getting the error TypeError: doc.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with array type variables then you should initialise state with empty array.

```
const [doc, setDocData] = React.useState([]).
```

So that when you use any of the array methods on the same variable it won't crash.

OR

If you still want to use `null` as default value for your array, then you can use

```
{
  doc?.map((user) => (
    <div key={user.uid}>
      <p>{user.uid}</p>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Here `?` operator will check whether `doc` has value or not and then only it will execute `.map` on it.

Comment: thanks. Using React.useState([]) I am getting doc.map is not a function

Comment: you might be setting non-array type data to `doc` that could be the reason.